# Casbah 3.0.0 API : Where is the MongoDBObject?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

In the getting started tutorial, we use `MongoDBObject`.

But I can't find it in the [api](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/3.0/scaladoc/).

Also, I don't understand how we can run this command : `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._`, can't find it in the API neither...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your `Imports` object: https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala#L141

`MongoDBObject` comes from one of Casbah modules, `casbah-commons`.
Check it out: https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-commons/src/main/scala/MongoDBObject.scala

Comment: I don't understand why I can't see these objects when I generate the doc with `sbt doc`

Comment: You do `sbt doc` in your project or you cloned casbah repo and do it there?

Comment: I cloned the casbah repo. And also on the online doc it is absent if you check.

Comment: You should find `casbah-commons` docs under *casbah-commons/target/scala-2.11/api*

Comment: Do you know how I could generate a unified doc of all the casbah-* with `sbt` ?

Comment: (This is a bit beyond the core of your question) check out: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc